# How to fix no networks showing on Ubuntu 20.04 when dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, power-management

If you know how to fix this then you are welcome to add an answer, however I have already fixed it but I want to make it easier for people who want to know how to because it took me about 3 hours to fix and it ended up just being editing 1 character in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

## Disabling power management for networking ( Ubuntu )

The solution that worked for me was disabling power management for the network card, because my WiFi was working for about 10 minutes after startup then would shut off, I figured it was probably a power management issue since I am dual booting.

Navigate to `etc/NetworkManager/conf.d`, then there should be 1 file called `default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`, open this file in any text editor, you will find this text:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

You will want to set `wifi.powersave` to `2` instead of `3`.

`3` means enabled, `2` means disabled, `1` means keep default value.
This will take effect on the next reboot.